# Is $H=\{(12),(13)\}$ a subgroup of $S_3?$ Yes/No

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is  $H=\{(12),(13)\}$  a subgroup  of $S_3?$

I think yes

Here $|H|=2$ and $|S_3|=6$

By Lagrange theorem  $2| 6 \implies  H$ is  a subgroup of $S_3$

Is it true ?

Comment: I think Lagrange works the other way around. In fact, given a finite group $G$ and a divisor $d$ of $|G|$, there does not necessarily exist a subgroup of $G$ with order $d$.

Comment: $H$ doesn't even have the identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT.** If $H$ is subgroup of a group $G$, then $H$ is itself a group, meaning it contains the identity and is closed under inverses, i.e. if $x, y \in H$, then $xy \in H$ and $x^{-1} \in H$.

Is the identity in $H$? What is $(12)(13)$ and is it in $H$?

**NOTE.** I suppose I should also comment on your proof/disproof attempt. Remember, Lagrange's Theorem works the other way around: that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $|H|$ divides $|G|$. But notice you then start with a subgroup, then you talk about the order. In your explanation, you have started with the order, then tried to talk about a subgroup.

The converse to Lagrange's Theorem, i.e. if $d$ divides $|G|$, then $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $d$, is generally false. For example, the group $A_4$, the $4$-alternating group, has order $12$ but no subgroup of order $6$.